# 関数と -e オプションを併用すると意図通りに動作しないのはなぜ？

Tags: sh

次のようなスクリプトを書きました。

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                  

set -e                                                                                                                     

hoge() {                                                                                                                   
    false                                                                                                                  
    echo "I don't want to see this message."                                                                               
}                                                                                                                          

hoge && \                                                                                                                  
    echo "... Nor this Message"
```

`-e` のオプションをセットしているので、何も表示されないだろうと期待していました。具体的には、

1. hoge 関数は、最初のコマンドが `false` なので、 set `-e` の効果によりエラー exit する。
2. hoge コマンドがエラー終了したので、 && の後半は実行されない。 もしくは、 最初の false を実行した時点でそもそも exit する。

しかし、出力は次の通りになります。

```
I don't want to see this message.                                                                                          
... Nor this Message
```

一体何がどうしてこれらのメッセージは表示されているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Man page of BASH](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html)によると、失敗したコマンドが、

- キーワード while または until の直後のコマンドの一部である場合
- 予約語 if または elifに続く条件式の一部である場合
- && または || によるコマンドのリストの一部である場合(最後の && や || の後のコマンドを除く)
- パイプラインの中の最後のコマンド以外である
- コマンドの返り値が ! で反転されている場合

のいずれかであれば、シェルは終了しない、という事です。

質問の例ですと`false`は関数中では単独で呼び出されていますが、その関数を呼び出しているのは`&&`を含んだコマンド列ですので、

> && または || によるコマンドのリストの一部

という事になるのだと思います。